# PIC16F57 Won't startup (MCLR?)

Tags: microcontroller, pic

This problem has me defeated!  I've created a binary clock for a scout merit badge project.  About 10 have been built and work but one scout's does not.  It appears to be related to proper startup of the PIC.  I created a simpler "blinktest.asm" to test with the same results.  Often outputs are flickering way faster than they should (I don't think the pic is running/stable.).  I've changed the crystal, crystal caps, resoldered the pic socket, swapped pics, swapped out the HC393 chip, tried different power supplies, etc.  The ONLY time the pic seems to run is if I power it with the Pickit3 AND check the voltage with a multimeter (it reads 4.78V, at some point it quits running and voltage changes to 4.81V).  It will not run with the eBay cheapo-no name power supply running at 5.50V.  I have 3 power supply caps in the circuit (I use 490-5401-ND CAP CER 0.1UF 50V RADIAL) and one of them is very close to pins 2 & 4.  Replacing the cap at the power supply connections to electrolytics of 10 or 100 uF did not help.  The resistor on the two first pins of the ICSP header (R2) is 10K.  The circuit behavior (runs or doesn't run) is the same whether I test with the original code or with the BlinkTest code.  Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Schematic]

```
      #include <P16F57.inc>         ; processor specific variable definitions
  LIST P=16F57, F=INHX8M, R=DEC

__CONFIG   _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _XT_OSC; & _PWRT_ON

;***** VARIABLE DEFINITIONS
Count_RTC_1s equ 8      ;cycles thru main loop, every 20 msec
Count_Secs equ 9            ;seconds, RTC
Count_Mins equ 10           ;minutes, RTC

; other registers
DCount equ 16            ;in a different bank from other variables!
DCountHi equ 17

  Constant TMR0_INIT=90     ;  one TMR0 overflow from TMR0_INIT to 256
  Constant TMR0_REINIT=100  ;  N-1 overflows from TMR0_REINIT to 256
            ;  This value cannot be zero.  Otherwise TMR0 will
            ;  automatically reenter main loop upon return to
            ;  PollTMR0 if TMR0 hasn't incremented yet.
  Constant N=50
;**********************************************************************
    ORG     0x7FF             ; processor reset vector
RESET CODE 0x00
    goto MainLine

;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
;  Subroutines
Blink_LED
  btfsc PORTC, 7
    goto LED_is_ON
  bsf PORTC, 7
  goto LED_Updated
LED_is_ON
  bcf PORTC, 7
LED_Updated
  Return

Delay198m               ;198 msec delay

  Banksel DCount
;  32.768 kHz   DCount=181  DCountHi=1
;  4 MHz        DCount=255  DCountHi=255

  movlw  255
  movwf  DCount
  movlw  255
  movwf  DCountHi

  decfsz DCount, f
    goto $-1
  decfsz DCountHi,f
    goto $-3

;LB
  Banksel Count_Secs
  return
;..........................

Delay20m                ;20 msec delay

  Banksel DCount
;  32.768 kHz   DCount=181  DCountHi=1
;  4 MHz        DCount=255  DCountHi=26

  movlw  255
  movwf  DCount
  movlw  26
  movwf  DCountHi

  decfsz DCount, f
    goto $-1
  decfsz DCountHi,f
    goto $-3

;LB
  Banksel Count_Secs
  return

;++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
;  PollTMR0 and Main Loop
PollTMR0             ;TMR0 is timer zero, it is always running per the XTAL.

  movf TMR0, 0          ;If TMR0=0, it's been 20msec - go on to main loop
  btfss STATUS, Z
    goto $-2                 ;Not zero, go back two lines.

; This is the MAIN LOOP!
  movlw TMR0_REINIT             ;Restart TMR0 with this value.
  movwf TMR0

  decfsz Count_RTC_1s, f        ;Has it been 1.000 second yet?
    goto PollTMR0                ;No.  Go back and poll TMR0 more.

;It's been a second!
  Banksel DCount
  movlw 32                          ; Need 66 instruction cycle delay
  movwf DCount          ; delay  = 2 + (2 X DCount) [in cycles]

  decfsz DCount, f
    goto $-1
  Banksel Count_Secs

  movlw TMR0_INIT           ;Restart TMR0 with this value.
  movwf TMR0
  movlw N                       ;It takes this many to get to 1.000 second.
  movwf Count_RTC_1s

  call Blink_LED

  goto PollTMR0                         ;Go back to polling TMR0 to see if it's timed out.

;+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
MainLine            ;initialize timing variables

;setup STATUS, TMR0 & I/O ports....

  call Delay198m        ;This delay added 7/31/99
  call Delay198m        ;One of 2 16C84s using for development got different
  call Delay198m        ;results for RCTime depending on POR or MCLR.
  call Delay198m        ;This delay made that difference go away.
  call Delay198m
  call Delay198m

  movlw 0x0D6       ; D6=1101 0110
                            ; TMRO from instruction cycle
                            ; prescaler for TMR0, prescaler=128
  option

;initializations

  movlw TMR0_INIT       ;Initialize TMR0 value.
  movwf TMR0
  movlw N
  movwf Count_RTC_1s

  movlw 0x000       ; 00=0000 0000
        ; all outputs
  TRIS PORTA ;& 0x07F
  movlw 0x000       ; 00=0000 0000
        ; all outputs
  TRIS PORTB ;& 0x07F
  movlw b'00000000' ; 00=0000 0000
        ; all outputs
  TRIS PORTC ;& 0x07F

  goto PollTMR0

  end
```

Comment: Your schematic has an interesting tendency to show the layout aspects of the board, as well as angled lines. This really isn't necessary in a schematic. Your layout may change later and this can cause you to have to change a lot in your schematic. 

In Eagle you should use a DOT for the junctions to ensure they're connected.

Comment: Is that your entire schematic?  I don't see any decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Gustavo  - Thanks for the suggestions!  And I apologize that I need to learn to move the component IDs around to make the schematic more legible.

Comment: Majenko - You're right.  They're on the schematic but I did not include them in the clip that I did.  It would probably be better to show them next to the ICs when that is where they are included.

Comment: Did I just solve my issue?  It appears I may have.  I added a 100 ohm resistor on the MCLR pin.  This is shown in some circuits and is discussed in the datasheet but I don't understand all of the explanation.  It appears to work now.

Answer (score -1):

The circuit has been running since I added the 100 ohm resistor on MCLR on 3/23/15 so it appears to be solved.

Comment: Why did this earn a downvote?